# Retrieve values from http://m.facebook.com/ajax/dtsg.php

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook

I need to retrieve values from http://m.facebook.com/ajax/dtsg.php.
The page source of it contains:

```
for (;;);"":"","token":"AQDUdkLT","expire":1320259533,"":"
```

`"token":"AQDUdkLT"` is unique for each user, so I can't use php.
I need some client side method to retrieve those values.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're trying to bypass the security model on the mobile site and scrape it.

Why not just use the API? Anything else you try is liable to break, get you blocked from Facebook or contacted by Facebook Security and/or Legal.

Comment: I just want to know thow can i do it

Comment: Those tokens are put in place specifically to prevent people faking requests to the mobile site in a way that would compromise security; if you found a way to work around the protection it would be fixed as soon as it was noticed